# Angular2 Routing with url params

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Is there an elegant solution – in the name of DRY – to the following route definition?

```
{ 
   path: CalendarComponent.path, /* the path is 'calendar' */
   component: CalendarComponent, 
   canActivate: [AuthGuard, EmployeeGuard],
   data: {
     navi: {
       at: 'main'
     },
     roles: {
       employeeOnly: true
     }
   },
},
{ 
   path: CalendarComponent.path + '/:urlString', 
   component: CalendarComponent, 
   canActivate: [AuthGuard, EmployeeGuard] 
}
```

With the same CalendarComponent I want to be able to serve

- xyz.com/**calendar**
- xyz.com/**calendar/2018-06-12**

I tried to define this routing as follows:

```
{ 
   path: CalendarComponent.path,
   component: CalendarComponent, 
   canActivate: [AuthGuard, EmployeeGuard],
   data: {
     navi: {
       at: 'main'
     },
     roles: {
       employeeOnly: true
     }
   },
   children: [
     {
        path: ':urlString',
        component: CalendarComponent
     }
   ]
}
```

but then it says `Cannot read property 'component' of null` @ router.js:3628, running into the same line of code as in [Angular 5 TypeError: outlet is null / cannot read property 'component' of null while routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616557/angular-5-typeerror-outlet-is-null-cannot-read-property-component-of-null-w)

Angular 5.1.0

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to create two seperate pages? or are you just trying to use the calendar page as a container for your ':urlstring' page??

Comment: I'm curious to know what your final solution was to this.  It bugs me that there is no obvious way in Angular to reference URL segment strings by name similar to how you wrote CalendarComponent.path.  I hadn't thought that DRY was the principle at work in this need to avoid hardcoding URLs so they don't break when renaming/refactoring routes, but I suppose it's strongly related.

Comment: I've left it as is. For now...

Answer (score 0):

Your set up should look more like this

```
{ 
  path: 'calendar/:urlstring', /* the path is 'calendar' */
  component: CalendarComponent, 
  canActivate: [AuthGuard, EmployeeGuard],
  data: {
    navi: {
     at: 'main'
    },
    roles: {
      employeeOnly: true
    }
  },
}
```

with this you will be able to go to xyz.com/calendar/2018-2-4 but not xyz.com/calendar because you will need to have the urlstring for the route to work, if you want to have calendar and then also have calendar/2018-2-12 you will need to create two seperate components and have the urlstring component nested inside the calendar component in a `router-outlet`